# I am getting error in .podspec file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

```
-> TestPod.podspec
    - ERROR | spec: The specification defined in `TestPod.podspec` could not be loaded.


[!] Invalid `TestPod.podspec` file: undefined local variable or method `“blabla”' for Pod:Module.

 #  from TestPod.podspec:30
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    s.author             = { “{blabla}” => "blablabla@gmail.com" }
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I am use 'pod spec lint TestPod.podspec --verbose' commnad in terminal.but return above error let me know if you have any chance to solve this.

Comment: `“{blabla}”` That's the real "quotes" that are present in your podspec? Because they are "stylized".

Comment: Do not open it in textEdit because it changes the characters. Instead open it with xcode and rewrite again "" quotes, u will understand the change in quote style.